# Active Record order by current day

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Im having an issue sorting an array by the current date.

my database has a field called `day`

`day` has the days of the week eg: `Monday`, `Tuesday`, etc.

I am trying to sort my index view page by the `current day`.

I would like to do somehting like this in my controller,

```
@happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id))
  .page(params[:page]) 
  .where(:day => Date.today.strftime('%A').capitalize.to_s)
```

but instead of returning `only` happies with the day `Monday` I would want to `order` by `day` where `day` is equal to the `current day`.

I also thought about doing this in my view

with something like

`<% @happies.sort_by(:day => Date.today.strftime('%A').capitalize.to_s).each do |happy| %>`

the above does not work but im trying to get accross what I wan to achieve.  Any ideas on how to implement this?

Maybe there is an activeview helper?

Comment: In your ideal scenario, what how would the rest of the ordering go? If today was Tuesday, would it go Tuesday -> Wednesday -> Thursday -> Friday -> Saturday -> Sunday -> Monday?

Comment: yes correct it would go `Tuesday -> Wednesday -> Thursday -> Friday -> Saturday -> Sunday -> Monday`

Comment: do you have an actual date column on these records as well? (besides the `day` column)

Comment: No just a day column with the Name of the day.

Comment: Would you be willing to save more than just the day of the week on your records? Then ordering would be trivial. You could still parse out the day of the week from the timestamp for display purposes.

Comment: @yez I could save more than the day of the week, but I would like to only save the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you were not paginating, you could sort the results in plain ruby like this:

```
day_order = %w(Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday Monday)
@happies = @happies.sort_by{|happy| day_order.index(happy.day)}
```

`sort_by` takes a block that returns the value to sort by.

However, you appear to be paginating using `will_paginate`. That's fine but it makes things more complicated.

The pagination necessarily happens in the database via limit and offset (so as to avoid returning the entire contents of the table to the Rails process). Therefore you want the sorting to also happen in the database. If you were to sort in ruby (as above) you would be sorting *after* pagination, meaning the first page would give you essentially random results, and then you'd sort them. Probably not what you want.

Long story short, you probably want to use `order` instead of `sort_by`, and I'm going to have to dip into SQL for this one:

```
@happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id))
    .page(params[:page])
    .order("CASE day WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 0 " \
                    "WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 1 " \
                    "WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 2 " \
                    "WHEN 'Friday' THEN 3 " \
                    "WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 4 " \
                    "WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 5 " \
                    "WHEN 'Monday' THEN 6 END")
```

If you want to avoid SQL, perhaps it is possible to use Arel for this, I'm not sure.

**Edit**

I see now you want to start with the current day, i.e. not hardcoded as Tuesday like I did. To fix my SQL version - and borrowing a bit from @Snarf's answer - you could do this:

```
days = %w(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday)
days.rotate!(days.index(Time.zone.now.strftime("%A")))
case_pieces = days.each_with_index.map do |day, i|
  "WHEN '#{day}' THEN #{i}"
end

@happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id))
    .page(params[:page])
    .order("CASE day #{case_pieces.join(' ')} END")
```

**Another thought**

If I was writing the app myself, I would be tempted to store the day as an integer from 0 to 6, instead of as a string.  Then you could order using the modulo operator, something like this:

```
days = %w(Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday)
day_offset = days.index(Time.zone.now.strftime("%A"))
@happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results.map(&:id))
    .page(params[:page])
    .order("(day - #{day_offset} + 7) % 7")
```

Comment: If you're doing this a lot then you could stash the string/number mapping in a separate table a JOIN to it; you could also use a JSON or hstore literal instead of the CASE if you're using PostgreSQL, or even JOIN to a VALUES expression. Personally, I find AREL solutions to be unreadable and opaque to the point of being nearly useless; AREL seems better suited to using software to build queries rather than being written by hand. IMO of course.

Comment: @muistooshort good point about putting the mapping in a separate table. And I agree about Arel - much less readable than SQL - but better than string manipulation if you are building a query programmatically.

Comment: How does your sql select on the current day?  I need to be selecting the day based on what the current day is.

Comment: nice, im getting an unexpected error end of input, maybe I need to put the above `case_pieces` in a lamda?

Comment: @ColtonSeal Sorry, I was missing a `)`. I've edited my answer again... (and again... and once more... :-) can you try now?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure ruby solution.

```
days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]

days.rotate(days.index(Time.now.strftime("%A")))

#=> ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
```

Comment: Actually could you explain in detail how I would accomplish this in the index view, with the code snippet you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same as @Snarf - this is only ruby and will not support pagination

```
today = Date.current.strftime('%A') 
# => Monday
days = Date::DAYNAMES 
# => ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
today_index = days.index(today) 
# => 1
@ordered_days = days.rotate(today_index)
# => ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
@happies = Happy.where(id: @search.results)


<!-- view -->
<% @ordered_days.each do |day| %>
  <!-- in memory selection from the @happies collection, could be emtpy -->
  <% occurring_on = @happies.select { |happy| happy.day == day } %>

  <%= day %>
  <% occuring_on.each do |happy| %>
    <%= happy %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```